# Why my Android SDK source is not complete?

Tags: java, android, javadoc

Recently I found my Android SDK source is not complete. I have downloaded the Android SDK API 16 ONLY from SDK Manager. When I want to generate the javadoc from source, it warns me that some classes are not found. I have read the website below, but I get confused whether the higher level API contains the lower level APIs. Is it enough to install the highest API only ?  Or do some of the Android SDK source depend on the JDK source ? Thanks a lot.

[Android API leve help](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

A piece of Javadoc warnings :

./java/lang/String.java:31: warning: package libcore.util not exist

import libcore.util.EmptyArray;

Comment: I had a similar issue, where the SDK code (which I got using SDK Manager) was referencing a particular string, but the relevant strings.xml wasn't included and I was so frustrated trying to find it to no avail - but I did find it within the full SDK! https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, SDK will include only sources from frameworks/base. Since libcore is not here (it is at the root of the source tree), you are getting this error.

Comment: How about "junit.runner.BaseTestRunner"? It imports "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError", but I can't find "framework" folder in "junit" folder in the source folder at all. You can check it out if you only install SDK API 16 ONLY. Thanks.

Comment: The AssertionFailedError is actually from AOSP_root/dalvik/dx/src/junit/framework/ and not from the sdk sources. SDK source is not the entire source. It simply works when you compile because we have the android.jar as a library in the project. You can open android.jar and see junit/framework/AssertionFailedError.class.

Comment: Thanks for your patient reply. But if I really want to get the complete SDK source code(Java), should I go to the Android project and git clone it? Why doesn't the official SDK Manager provide developers with the full source code? That's strange, right?

Comment: To get the entire source, follow instructions in [dev docs](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). The thing is, the entire source has a lot of files most of which are not helpful to you as an app developer - you only need the files for the commonly used classes, widgets, etc. Moreover the source tree also has a lot of non-standardized apis which are not supposed to be used by a developer. Hence the minimal 'sdk'.

Comment: Thanks for your patient reply.